# diagonalizing a hadamard product

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, products, hadamard-product

I have looked at various answers on hamadamard products, but none of them seem to answer this.

Given a matrix $M=F\circ G$ where $F=UDU^{-1}$ is diagonalizable and $G=xx^T$ is rank 1. Is there way I can diagonalize $M$ or know the eigen values of $M$? Even computing the square root of $M$ would be interesting for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to re-formulate the problem without reference to the Hadamard product (whose drawback is that it has few properties by itself).

Let $$\tag{1}x=(x_1,x_2,... x_n) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \Delta:=diag(x_1,x_2,... x_n).$$

Then $$\tag{2}F \circ G = \Delta F \Delta.$$

Straightforward proof: left-multiplying (resp right-multiplying) by diag$(x_1,x_2,... x_n)$ amounts to multiply the k-th row (resp. th k-th column)by $x_k$.

Example with $n=2$:

$$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} \circ \left(\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}*\pmatrix{x_1&x_2}\right)=\pmatrix{x_1&0\\0&x_2} *\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} *\pmatrix{x_1&0\\0&x_2}$$

(where * denotes the usual matrix product).

The question is now: are there relationships between the eigenvalues of $F$ and those of $\Delta F \Delta$ ?

I am tempted to say that an answer is that the more $\Delta$ is away from $I_n$ (Identity matrix) (otherwise the more $X$ is far away from $(1,1,\cdots 1)$), the less connection one has with the initial eigenvalues. Here is an example that illustrates that with the $3 \times 3$ matrix:

$$F=\pmatrix{0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\\3&3&1}$$

whose eigenvalues are $1$ and $\pm\sqrt{3}$ (red points on graphics below).

Edit: I have taken 5000 realizations of $F \circ G$, where $G=XX^T$ with $X=(1+\epsilon_1,1+\epsilon_2,1+\epsilon_3)^T$ where the $\epsilon_k$s have (small) uniform variations in  $[-1/4,1/4]$. Here are the 5000 results ($3 \times 5000$ points representing the eigenvalues. One can observe rather important fluctuations around the initial eigenvalues:

[image]

Comment: Im not entirely sure if that helps, or am i missing something (correct me if I am). So $F\circ G= \Delta F \Delta =\Delta U D_F U^{-1} \Delta$ and it could very well be that $\Delta$ is not full rank (or it could be the identity matrix with some of the ones replaced by 0s on the diagonal). In that case, what more can we say?

Comment: 1) I have a little updated my answer. 2) The rank of $\Delta$ is exactly the number of zero entries in $(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n)$. It is possible that it has some direct incidence on the rank of $F \circ G$, if $F$ is full rank...

Comment: Hmm, agreed on that. it is still surprising to me, that even if we know that F is diagonalizable, we cant compute the eigen values of $F\circ G$

Comment: This is not so surprising. Even when there is a unique matrix multiplication (from $A$ to $AB$), there are no connection (up to my knowledge) between the eigenvalues of $A$ and those of $AB$. And from $F$ to $ \Delta (F \Delta)$, there a two matrix products...

Comment: I have added a graphical example.